# get notified when spring boot healtcheck status changes

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a way to get notified when the status of the registered health check indicators changes? For example, when the healthcheck indicator of database becomes down, I would like to take some actions.

Actually, my final goal is to export healthcheck status to Prometheus' metrics. So, when there is status change, I want to update health metrics.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your question refers to Micrometer [issue 416](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/416) and Micrometer-Docs [issue 39](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/issues/39).

As per documentation, you can register the custom `HealthMetricsConfiguration`. The value of the gauge is determined by the status the `ComposeHealthIndicator` returns and is actually changing depending on the state of the single `HealthIndicator`s.

I am using afformentioned `HealthMetricsConfiguration` (just with different status value mappings as discussed in issue 416).

Wen't ahead and implemented a custom alternating health indicator:

```
@Component
public class AlternatingHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Builder builder) throws Exception {
        int minute = LocalDateTime.now().getMinute();
        boolean minuteIsEven = minute % 2 == 0;
        builder.status(minuteIsEven ? Status.UP : Status.DOWN);
        builder.withDetail("description", "UP when current minute is even; DOWN when current minute is odd");
        builder.withDetail("currentMinute", minute);
        builder.withDetail("minuteIsEven", minuteIsEven);
    }

}
```

The `health` gauge exported on the Prometheus endpoint is minutely changing from `1=UP` to `-2=DOWN`. Here's a visualization:

[image: alternating health status visualized in Grafana, queried from Prometheus]

Regarding alerting, you can use Grafana alerting or look into Prometheus' Alertmanager.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I can create an additional health indicator. And the code you shared below only does this. But the question is how can I pass it to Prometheus? I think I can create custom metrics for Prometheus during this health checking?

Comment: As you've been commenting in the Micrometer project issues I assume you have added `micrometer-registry-prometheus` in your project and you already are aware of the fact that you can then reach [http://myapp:port/actuator/prometheus]. (You might need to enable this endpoint explicitely with the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include` property) Under this endpoint you will then see a metric named `health` (of type gauge) which indicates the health status. This metric is created from the code in the micrometer documentation. That endpoint should then be scraped by Prometheus.

Comment: Alright, I just realized that only using HealthMetricsConfiguration is enough to have the indicators passed to metrics. So, I did not need any additional health indicator. thanks. I got what I want but I still curious about if there is a way to get notified when health status changes.

Comment: I was adding the `AlternatingHealthIndicator` as an example to prove the fact the accumulated health indicator status is reflected in the `health` metric. (As you mentioned in the tickets/issues that only the initial status was reflected, which is not the case.) Regarding alerting, you need to setup a monitoring solution where these metrics are exported to, or pulled into. You will want to alert there, not within your app. You'd have to setup an alerting mechanism in every app then which is not the best idea IMHO. That's why I recommended to have a look at Grafana or Prometheus alerting.

Comment: sure, I use prometheus and grafana; and setup alerts in prometheus. My curiosity about getting notified for any change is not related to having alerts. In other words, is there any event emitted by health checking so I can listen to them with ApplicationListener?

Comment: Ah! Now I get it. Got mislead by the prometheus label on the question. I don't think there is such an `ApplicationEvent`, as the health status' are queried in a pull-model. When you don't ask the health endpoint, nobody will tell somethings broken. What I could imagine is setting up a `@Scheduled` method which does use the very same CompositeHealthIndicator querying and then you'd fire your own `ApplicationEvent` derivate and have some `ApplicationListener` process it.